# How to safe a ObservableCollection within a ObservableCollection in xamarin.forms with Sqlite.net

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, sqlite-net

Last 3 days i tried to save my collection in my database.
I tried it in all sorts of ways... without success.
The last one i tried is to serialize my collection and save it to a byte[] everytime the collection changes.
And on appstart i tried to derserialize it in my collection.

I'm just trying to show the most important thing's.

I can save and reload this class without problems from my database.

```
[Serializable]
    public class MainElement : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public static int count = 0;
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public byte[] _elements;

        private ObservableCollection<SecondElement> elements;


        [OneToMany]
        public ObservableCollection<SecondElement> Elements 
        {
            get
            {
                return elements;
            }
            set 
            { 
                elements = value;
                this.SerializeElementsFromMainElement();
                //_elements = ExtensionAndDb.SerializeElementsFromMainElement(elements);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainElement()
        {
            Id = count++;
            Elements = new ObservableCollection<SecondElement>();
            this.DeSerializeElementsFromMainElement();
            //Elements = ExtensionAndDb.DeSerializeElementsFromMainElement(_elements);  
        }    

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
        public void DeSerializeElementsFromMainElement()
        {            
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(_elements);
            using (stream)
            {
                Elements = bf.Deserialize(stream) as ObservableCollection<SecondElement>;
            }
        }
        public void SerializeElementsFromMainElement()
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (stream)
            {
                bf.Serialize(stream, Elements);
                _elements = stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Every MainElement is stored in the MainList (ObservableCollection).
Everything is fine.

But i cant save or reload the `public byte[] _elements;` from/to the collection.

I know my code is not good, but if anyone has an idea or can show me how to save the `public ObservableCollection<SecondElement> Elements` with my class together in Sqlite, i would be really grateful.
I've been trying for 3 days

if you need more code, let me know.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you want to serialize and deserialie ObservableCollection, I suggest you ca use **Newtonsoft.Json** to do this.

Installing **Newtonsoft.Json** by Nuget package firstly.

For example, I do one esample:

```
public class person
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<person> persons { get; set; }
private string list;
    public Page13()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        persons = new ObservableCollection<person>()
        {
            new person(){username="cherry",age=12},
            new person(){username="barry",age=14}
        };

    }
```

Btn1.clicked is to serialize data, Btn2.clicked is to deserialize data.

```
 private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons);

    }

    private void Btn2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var myValue = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<person>>(list) ;
    }
```

If the Observablecollection changed, you can query this data by Id or other, then update this data.

Here is the article about Update, insert and save data in sqlite, you can take a look:

https://dzone.com/articles/register-and-login-using-sqlite-in-xamarinforms